# Why is my Mongo document not saving properly through Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

```
//reportconfig.js    
//Load up the report model
var Report = require('../models/report');
console.log('Report ' + Report);

//expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(req) {
    console.log('exporting' + req.body.address);
    var newReport = new Report();
    console.log('local ' + newReport.local.address);

    newReport.address = req.body.address;
    newReport.city = req.body.city;
    newReport.state = req.body.state;

    console.log('save ' + newReport.save);

    newReport.save(function(err) {
        console.log('saving ' + newReport.address);
        if(err) {
            console.log('error ' + err);
            throw err;
        }
        //return newReport;
    })
}


//server.js

//set up=======================================================
//get all the tools we need
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

// configuration =============================================================================
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);//I NEED TO FIGURE OUT HOW TO CONNECT TO MY LOCAL DB

require('./config/passport')(passport);//pass passport for configuration
var report = require('./config/reportconfig');

//set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev'));//log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser());//read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser());//get information from html forms

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); //set up ejs for templating

//required for passport
app.use(session({secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch'}));//session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());//persistent login sessions
app.use(flash());//use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

//routes ======================================================================================
require('./routes/routes.js')(app, passport, report);// load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

//launch ======================================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);

//routes.js
    app.post('/report', function(req, res) {
        report(req);
        console.log('res ' + res);
        res.redirect('/profile');
    });


// app/models/report.js
// load the things we need
console.log('model');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


// define the schema for our user model
var reportSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local : {

        address : String,
        city : String,
        state : String

    }

});


// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('Report', reportSchema);
```

What happens when I post to /report is that the model gets invoked and save is called.  The database gets a new entry, but it only has _id, not any of the other fields.  There is no error.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I can supply more information if you ask.  The code above is from three separate files
The model is loading correctly because printing Report works.  All fields of newReport are valid as well.

Comment: How is `Report` defined in `../models/report`? What is the `Schema` structure used for it? Is the difference between `newReport.address` (assignment) and `newReport.local.address` (logged) significant or are they both available fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newReport.address`, etc. aren't being defined in the `Schema`. So, to uphold it, Mongoose is removing them as part of the `.save()`.

To match the schema, the reads and assignments need to use `newReport.local`:

```
newReport.local.address = req.body.address;
newReport.local.city = req.body.city;
newReport.local.state = req.body.state;
```

```
console.log('saving ' + newReport.local.address);
```

Or, if it's not being used, `local` could be removed from the `Schema`:

```
var reportSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    address : String,
    city : String,
    state : String
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is so obvious now, but I never would have realized that.  I was basing this on a tutorial that did use the local field, I thought it was part of a standard schema!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the local inside your schema. When you are saving your using `newReport.address` which is not defined in the schema. It would instead be `newReport.local.address` if you wanted to keep the same structure. Here is the documentation which defines mongoose schema methods: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

```
mongoose.model('Report', reportSchema);

var reportSchema = mongoose.Schema({

   address : String,
   city : String,
   state : String

});
```